# How to show $B_n(f)^2\le B_n(f^2)$

Tags: approximation, weierstrass-approximation

> Show that $B_n(f)^2 \le B_n(f^2)$ where $B_n(f)$ is Bernstein's polynomials. HINT : Expand $B_n((f-a)^2)$

I really do not know how to solve it only a hint.

according to HINT 
$$B_n((f-a)^2)=B_n(f^2-2af)+a^2$$

and then how to derive given inequality? please give me a hint!
[image]

Comment: There's a typo, it should be $B_n((f-a)^2)=B_n(f^2-2af)+a^2$. And how do you define $\le$ for polynomials? If $f(x)=x$, you have $B_1(f)=B(f^2)=x$, so in which sense is $x^2\le x$? $p_1\le p_2$ iff $p_1(x)\le p_2(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ would make sense **in this context**, but the definition should be part of your question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Rignt I mistyped sorry.! and $f$ might be any continuous function. there isn't any other information about $f$ in my text book

Answer (score 1):

Since the basis polynomials $P^n_k(x)=\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ are $\ge0$ on $[0,1]$, $f\ge0$ implies $B_n(f)\ge0$ on $[0,1]$. So $B_n((f-a)^2)=B_n(f^2)-2aB_n(f)+a^2\ge0$ on $[0,1]$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Now put $a=B_n(f)$.

Comment: ha It is always easy to see when answer is shown. anyway I really appreciate your help. thank you!!